# click event on angular UI grid cell

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, grid

i would like my grid cell to handle the click event & display a pop up.

e.g if I click employee Id column a pop up should come with details of that employee

Answer (score 0):

you have here some functions that are called the those events are triggered

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope, getDataDown);
        gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreDataTop($scope, getDataUp);

        gridApi.edit.on.cancelCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef) {
            cancelCellEdit(rowEntity, colDef);
        });

        gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            validateCell(rowEntity);
        });

        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            abortInvalidValue(rowEntity, newValue, oldValue);
            afterCellEdit(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue);
        });

        controller.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
```